# To Check Session is null or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

In the below code I have Session variable in which I want to check whether it is null or not. Please help me to do this.
(`SearchDoc`) is class.

```
var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
var oDocumentID = SearchDoc.ClientID;
var Documentid = SearchDoc.DocumentID;

if (SearchDoc == null)
{

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `Session["Documentname"] != null`

Comment: Use `var SearchDoc = Session["Documentname"] as SearchDoc;` so you can check the variable if it is null with no exception thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(Session["Documentname"] != null)
{
    var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
    var oDocumentID = SearchDoc.ClientID;
    var Documentid = SearchDoc.DocumentID;

    if (SearchDoc == null)
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the safest approach :

```
 if ((HttpContext.Current.Session !=null && Session["Documentname"] as SearchDoc!= null))
{

 //do what you want with
  ((SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"])

}
```

2 things to notice :

- Yes  , sometime the session object is null. ( probably occurs with AShX's without appropriate interface)
- use the AS operator. - once it's ok , you can safely cast to SearchDOC

Comment: If `Session["Documentname"]` is `null` then I think its not possible to cast `SearchDoc`

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session` will give all `sessions` or just `Session["Documentname"]`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj you dont always have the session object instantiated. (depends on your stage) ( for example  - in ASHX)

Comment: @Bharadwaj re-checked  - you dont need to check that.

Comment: I mean `if (null as Task!=null) {}` is a valid statement

Comment: Yes, just now I checked it. I don't know this is a feature or mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this:

```
string oDocumentID = string.Empty;
string Documentid = string.Empty;

if(Session["Documentname"] != null){
 var SearchDoc = (YourSearchDocType)Session["Documentname"];
 oDocumentID = SearchDoc.ClientID;
 Documentid = SearchDoc.DocumentID;

 // some code
}
```

dont try to access some property of object which can be null